# 'Start' equivalent in OS X

Tags: macos, command-line

In Windows, from a Shell you can type in 'start' to open another shell instance. What is the equivalent command in OS X?

Comment: This is a superuser question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

⌘N (Command+N).

For the other use of `start`, to open arbitrary files with their associated application, use `open` on OS X.

Comment: +1 .... side question what's the equivalent of windows Command-R to start programs like an initial shell? Right now, I use spotlight or google desktop shell.

Comment: I use spotlight, Command+Space, type a few letters, select top hit. Some people use a launcher like Quicksilver for this purpose.

Comment: I use/love Google's quick search box (similar to Quicksilver, made by the author of Quicksilver who now works for google...): http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/

Answer (score 4):

From Finder to the following:

1. Finder -> Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal (This opens he terminal application).
2. To open a new terminal window ⌘N (Command +N)
3. To open a new tab within the existing window ⌘T (Command+T)

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
```

Answer (score 1):

open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
will open a window if there is none, but it won't start another Terminal instance.

osascript -e "tell app \"terminal\"" -e "do script\"\"" -e "end tell"
will tell the running instance to open a new window.

Ugly, but functional.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to start a command (in my case `tail` ing a log file) and keep it running:

```
echo "tail -n 70 -f /tmp/livy.log" >> /tmp/xyz && chmod u+x /tmp/xyz && open -a /Applications/utilities/Terminal.app /tmp/xyz
```

I suppose something similar might be done for keeping a general purpose bash prompt around - along the lines of `bash -c <some command>`

Answer (score -1):

Although I suspect that command-N is what you were after, there is also a unix command called `screen` you can use to detach and attach console sessions.
Type `man screen` to read up on how it works.